# Container like div, span etc

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to create a container like a `div`?
The problem is that I have 4 controls (`TextView`, `Buttons` and `EditView`), and I want to center these. But instead of doing them one by one, I was wondering if there is a smart way of doing this. In web application, using `css`, we can do this on a `div`:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: xxx;
width: yyy;
```

Then the `div` will be centered on the page

Is there a similar way in when creating android apps?

Answer (score 11):

In XML, the equivalent of a `Div`, is a `ViewGroup`.

Example: `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc.

ViewGroups can contain Views and Controls like: `TextView`, `Button` and `EditView`.

[More ViewGroup Subclasses](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

**I created an example of what I *think* you're asking:**

I used a `LinearLayout` to hold our Views and Controls.

Then I used `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`, on our `LinearLayout`, to center the children.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <EditView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Demo]

Comment: just out of curiosity ... if I use Button, will I be able to control its styling and behaviors like I can when using a div or span?? ... ... (in html I never use the built in buttons because they have so many built-in behaviors and styles ... I always use divs or spans, and add event listening as needed for button capability)

Answer (score 1):

```
android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal|right|left"
```

Comment: I extrapolated your answer below.

Comment: Could you explain what this is doing? I understand something like `center_vertical`, but why the different values piped together?

Comment: it is for example. you can put one of them or several